# Find the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $[x]=2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $[x]=2$.

I just saw the question & find it confusing,  and that's why, for a relevant answer, I posted It here!

Comment: What do you mean by $[x]$?

Comment: By $[ x ]$ you mean the greatest integer no greater than $x$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Answer is [2,3).

Comment: If $[x]$ is the greatest integer function, than it is simply the set $[2,3)$

Answer (score 3):

$\lfloor x\rfloor:=\max\{z \in \mathbf{Z}: z\le x\}$, hence
$$
\lfloor x\rfloor=2 \Longleftrightarrow x \in [2,3).
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that, for every real $x$, the number $[ x ]$ denotes the greatest integer $\leq x$ by definition. Note that $[ x ] =2$ if and only if $2 \leq x < 3$. Indeed, we have $x < 2$ iff $[ x ] < 2$ and $x \geq 3$ iff $[x] \geq 3$.

For your reference, usually one uses $\lfloor x \rfloor$ to denote the greatest integer no greater than $x$, considering to reserve a symbol also for the least integer no less than $x$, which is denoted by $\lceil x \rceil$. For example, if $x=2.2$, then $\lfloor x \rfloor = 2$ and $\lceil x \rceil = 3$ by definition.